# Generating celery logs in JSON format in docker with supervisord

Tags: docker, nginx, celery, supervisord, graylog

I want to generate celery logs in json format for integration with greylog. Currently i'm using a command in supervisord.conf to generate celery logs in txt format like this:

```
[program:celeryworker]
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=celery worker -A d2i_app.celery --loglevel=info --logfile=celery_logs.txt
```

I'm unable to find the changes i need to do in this file to generate logs in JSON format.

If it's not possible to generate logs in JSON format from here, then what changes do i need to make in celery file for which i'm generating logs.

Comment: Not a celery guy but from what I read I think you need to create custom python logging handler. Check this https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/08/28/celery-logging/ . Maybe that helps

Comment: I recently found this library from new relic that outputs supervisor logs as json: https://github.com/newrelic/supervisor-remote-logging